# Group by in api-platform

Tags: php, api, symfony, api-platform.com

How to add a simple **group by** in api-platform queryString?

I would like to eliminate the duplicates

**Example:**

DATA:
database:

[image]

> [www.mySite.com/api/MyEntity.json?groupBy=Name](http://www.mySite.com/api/MyEntity.json?groupBy=Name)

How to To get this result:

[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: Something like https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/1226?

Comment: Also, could it be easier to avoid that duplicates get persisted to the database in the first place?